# A way to cap a hole

Tags: 3dsmax, 3ds

I got a piece of hollow sphere and I need to cap the hole on it. But Cap Holes modifier doesn't work for me. I also tried to select vertices, but still no result. Picture is related. The "hole" is highlighted.
[My object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4T7r.png)

Answer (score 0):

because that's not a hole. You need to delete the faces inside the sphere to be able to cap it